# CJ Date: Classic VB Wizard Upgrade or Should Re-design?

Tags: database, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Should I run a classic VB6 app thru the upgrade wizard in VS08 or should I re-design it from scratch.

The database is a mess.

Originally designed in ACCESS and imported to MS SQL SERVER.

The main entities are e.g. ROLLER_SKATES and RENTALS. If you would like to rent a pair of roller skates you can. So this more or less comprises an Inventory system for the roller skates.

Now you have 2 different skating rings. Skate-B1 and Skate-Z9, and you keep redundant and duplicate data from the previously mentioned entities in the skating ring tables as well.

It's a nightmare.

At least the tables have row ID's. But no explicit foreign keys, just implicit columns identically named that "seem" to correspond to each other. But the rest of the table's attributes all default to NULL.

Considering what C.J Date says about Types in his book SQL and the Relation Model, isn't it desirable to have CHECK CONSTRAINTS on attributes?

And, the data is all over the place, e.g., Roller skate serial number is G123 and then in another instance it is G-123. Get the drift?

What should I do?

Comment: I think you answered your own question, if the application is as messed up as you say it is this would be the perfect time to redesign the application. Even though the upgrade wizard is a lot better than it used to be, it still will add an additional source of confusion

Comment: Sounds like you want to restructure the **database** not the **application**?

Comment: MarkJ, you are right, I do want to restructure the db, but my pm is a putts and is trying to block me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without spending too much time reading your question, two lines jump out at me:

> The database is a mess.

> It's a nightmare.

**So, I think we can both agree that a rewrite is the most desirable course.**

However, that has to be balanced with your particular requirements. How fast does the migration have to take place? Is the current app *unusuable* until it is rewritten? If so, that might be a pretty compelling argument in favor of using the Upgrade Wizard. Even given its flaws and shortcomings, it's going to be easier than a total rewrite from scratch.

If you do decide to go this route and use the Upgrade Wizard, a third "balanced" option presents itself, which I *highly* recommend. Once you upgrade your project and get it to compile using the Upgrade Wizard (and your friendly neighborhood Stack Overflow as a resource), you can distribute and begin using the new .NET version of your app. Then, slowly, you can start redesigning and reimplementing parts of the now .NET version of the app. As long as you keep the same public interfaces, and only redesign small portions of your application's code base, you can roll out these changes slowly, essentially rewriting the entire application in stages. It might take you a few months to get the low-level database access code right, but in the meantime, your application works. Then, once you get that code working right and polished, you can go ahead and roll it out to the next incremental version of your app, while you work on the UI code behind the scenes.

Comment: +1. Incremental refactoring of working applications is usually best. Another consideration is, how big is the application? Often they are larger than they seem at first impression, but it sounds really tiny from the question.

Comment: MarkJ, my archnemesis in the shop claims that test-driving web application development is not applicable(silly). He claims that tdd and unit tests are intended for algorithmic and calculation oriented applications. He claims that business apps, which he likes to characterize as "Data In Data Out", would not benefit from testable code. He comes from a PHP background really and is writing ASP.NET pages in PHP style. See my other post soon about "How do I test-drive ASP.NET WebForms development in VS08"

Answer (score 1):

If the app is anything like you original post, I would recomend redo and redesign.

You have the skeleton, and know what the idea behind the app is.

Very seldomly when we look back at apps that we design, do we find it to be perfect. This only happens if you did not progress as a programmer over the years...

Answer (score 1):

Redesigning and re-factoring are great, but sometimes you just have to realize that the crappy little project you're maintaining is just that, and will never be any better.  You have to think about things from the customers perspective.  To them it's just one of the pieces of equipment they use to get a job done.  If it's working they probably don't see any reason to spend any money at all on it, especially if it's some kind of upgrade they can't see or really understand.

I've upgraded several such projects from VB6 back in the day. Maybe the converters are better now, but I didn't have a lot of luck with them.  What I've found works pretty well is to make new forms that look like the old ones.  Then copy and paste the code from the old form into the new form and work through the bugs.  It goes pretty quick.  I usually manage to slip in a few little improvements too, mostly to the UI where the customer will see that they're getting something for their money.

As for the backend I've worked with some large DBs w/o foreign key constraints and all the other problems you've talked about.  It's not ideal for maintainability but it works fine, and it doesn't sound like this is the sort of project that sees much maintenance.  You do need to make sure you find a way to enforce a unique single name for each item though, what ever you do.  I've seen other apps make that same mistake, and it leads to all kinds of problems.

If by some miracle you are able to convince them to budget some money on it, I would start from scratch.   Just remember things are always bigger and take longer than you think they will.  And don't forget you'll have to write some kind of data importer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The more complicated the project, the LESS likely you'll want to just upgrade and continue as is.

.Net provides so many more features than VB6 did, and while sure, it'll basically run vb6 code, there's no point in upgrading to .net if you're not actually going to USE .net and its features.

If the app is as messy as you say, converting to .net is a great time to both redesign to remove old inefficiencies and logical goofiness, and leverage the new things you're allowed in .net.  Even if it's not a TOTAL redesign, at least thinking about the app in terms of .net will improve it.

Unless the application is trivial in size/complexity, redo it.  And if the app isn't large or complres... redo it :)